# Select records where many-to-many relationship is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ancestry

I have a many-to-many relationship between `folder` and `user`

```
class Folder
    has_many :folder_share_authorities, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :shared_users, through: :folder_share_authorities, source: :user
end

class User
    has_many :folder_share_authorities, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :shared_folders, through: :folder_share_authorities, source: :folder
end

class FolderShareAuthority < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :folder
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I have my folders table structured with `ancestry` gem.

Now, when I share a folder with an user (create a `FolderShareAuthority` relationship), how can I have all descendants of that folder also shared with that user too?

I also had a pair index to make sure one `user` only has 1 relationship with one `folder`. So I think I should select all descendants haven't been shared with user yet first, then create relationship for this descendants ?

```
class CreateFolderShareAuthorities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    .......
    add_index :folder_share_authorities, [:folder_id, :user_id], unique: true
end
```

p/s: descendants of a folder can be query by just `folder.descendants` command (from `ancestry` gem)